# Decorrelation between a system and a harmonic bath

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm going through the section on generalized Langevin equation (Chapter 15) in Mark Tuckerman's textbook *Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Molecular Simulation*, and there is a property that I am struggling to prove: that the force (eqn 15.2.11)
$$
R(t)=-\sum_\alpha g_\alpha\left[\left(x_{\alpha0}+\frac{g_\alpha}{m_\alpha\omega_\alpha^2}q_0\right)\cos\omega_\alpha t+\frac{p_{\alpha0}}{m_\alpha\omega_\alpha}\sin\omega_\alpha t\right]
$$
is de-correlated with the system $\{q,p\}$ (thereby being a stochastic) iff $\langle p_0R(t)\rangle=\langle q_0R(t)\rangle=0$.

The Hamiltonian of the system+bath is quadratic (supposing the simplest form $V(q)\approx (1/2)kq^2$)
$$
\mathcal{H}=\frac{p^2}{2\mu}+V(q)+\sum_\alpha\left[\frac{p_\alpha^2}{2m_\alpha}+\frac12k_\alpha x_\alpha^2\right]+q\sum_\alpha g_\alpha x_\alpha.
$$
So noting that $R(t)=R(q_0;x_{\alpha0},p_{\alpha0};t)$, it is straightforward that $\langle p_0R(t)\rangle=0$ due to parity. But $q_0R(t)$ is even in $q_0$. So I don't see how its ensemble average is also zero. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's one of those times when I realize my mistakes and find an answer 30 seconds after asking it. For posterity, here are the details.

Since $q_0R(t)$ is independent of $p$ and $p_\alpha$, the integral over $dpdp_\alpha$ evaluates trivially. We diagonalize the rest of the Hamiltonian by completing the square
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}[q,q_\alpha]
=V(q)+\frac12k_\alpha x_\alpha^2+g_\alpha x_\alpha q
=V(q)-\frac{g_\alpha^2}{2k_\alpha}q^2+\frac12k_\alpha\left(x_\alpha+\frac{g_\alpha}{k_\alpha}q\right)^2.
\end{align}
$$
By a unitary transformation $q\mapsto q$ and $x_\alpha\mapsto x_\alpha+(g_\alpha/k_\alpha)q$, we can now evaluate
\begin{align}
\langle q_0R(t)\rangle
&\propto -g_\alpha\int dqdq_\alpha\exp{\left\{-\beta\left[V(q)+\frac12k_\alpha x_\alpha^2+g_\alpha x_\alpha q\right]\right\}}\\
&\qquad \times q\left(x_\alpha+\frac{g_\alpha}{k_\alpha}q\right)\cos\omega_\alpha t\\
&=-g_\alpha\cos\omega_\alpha t\int dqdq_\alpha\exp\left\{-\beta\left[V(q)-\frac{g_\alpha^2}{2k_\alpha}q^2+\frac12k_\alpha x_\alpha^2\right]\right\} x_\alpha q,
\end{align}
which is clearly zero, now that the Hamiltonian is diagonalized.

Comment: +1 for taking the effort to clarify!